# Is it always acceptable to publish working papers on your website before submission to a journal?

Tags: publications

Or will some journals reject submissions if you have already published them on a website?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why one would want to take this risk?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make sure what your rights are, including:

- preprint publication before submission
- preprint publication after acceptance
- publication of revised version
- publication of publisher's version

check your journal at http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/index.php

Comment: And check your target journal's publication policy. Most (if not all) journals are clear about what you can and cannot do regarding pre-print publication and self-archiving.

Comment: @Guillaume That’s exactly what the answer is saying.

Answer (score 1):

If the journal has blind peer review, make sure that the working paper has at least a different title from the submitted manuscript. Otherwise the editor may reject your paper, because reviewers could find your working paper, and this would compromise the anonymity of the review. (A reviewer's job includes checking whether the work is original. In doing so, s/he could stumble upon the working paper.)